# Try to add library to gradle

Tags: android, git, maven, android-gradle-plugin

I wrote a library and trying to set up a gradle dependency in the project. Made on a lesson from this site:http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en 
Everything went well, registered on the site, create a repository, created and saved keys. But when he moved to the files in the project were mistakes.
Below are the screenshots:
[image: My repo on Bintray] 
 version created myself through the site 
My project gradle file:

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.4'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
// Plugin used to upload authenticated files to BinTray through Gradle
plugins {
    id "com.jfrog.bintray" version "1.5"
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My library gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

ext {
    bintrayRepo = 'maven'
    bintrayName = 'AnimLib'
    publishedGroupId = 'diplom.itis.animationlib'
    libraryName = 'animlib'
    artifact = 'animlib'
    libraryDescription = ''
    siteUrl = 'https://github.com/metalink94/AnimationLib'
    gitUrl = 'https://github.com/metalink94/AnimationLib.git'
    libraryVersion = '0.9.0'
    developerId = 'metalink94'
    developerName = 'Denis'
    developerEmail = 'denisnovikov94@gmail.com'
    licenseName = 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
    licenseUrl = 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
    allLicenses = ["Apache-2.0"]
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        group = 'diplom.itis.animationlib' // Change this to match your package name
        version = '0.9.0' // Change this to match your version number

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'
    apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

}
apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nuuneoi/JCenter/master/installv1.gradle'
apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nuuneoi/JCenter/master/bintrayv1.gradle'
```

My app module gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "diplom.itis.animationlib"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.wangjiegulu:AndroidInject:1.0.6'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    compile 'com.alexvasilkov:android-commons:1.2.4'
    compile 'diplom.itis.animationlib:animlib:0.9.0'
    //compile project(':animlib')
}
```

And my error when I try sync gradle:
[image]

Please somebody help me, tell me where I get mistake?

**UPDATE** 
I don't have what you(Fondesa) underline at bottom left
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The process you have done is correct, you can do still two things, I'll post a screenshot to explain it better:

[image]

1. check that your dependency is linked to `jCenter`, you can find the button in the bottom-right part of your project general settings
2. check that your dependency declaration `diplom.itis.animationlib:animlib:0.9.0` in your `build.gradle` file matches with the one I underlined in the bottom-left part of my screenshot.

Comment: I update my question, i can't find what you underline at bottom left..in my package

Comment: @metalink open your 0.9.0 library on Bintray and go on "Files" tab, navigate into folders, can you find a file with ".pom" extension?